# How can I solve limit with absolute value $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to -\infty } {{x} \over {9}}|{\sin}{{6} \over {x}}|$

Tags: limits

I try to evaluate this limit by **L'Hopitals rule**, but I don't know how affect limit absolute value. Can someone give me some advice please?

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to -\infty } {{x} \over {9}}|{\sin}{{6} \over {x}}|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'Hôpital is not a magical thing to be used all the time. Thinking is advantageous.

If you want to consider $x\to-\infty$, you will only be dealing with $x<0$. So the numbers $6/x$ are going to be negative and close to zero. In that zone, the sine is negative, so 
$$
\left|\sin\frac6x\right|=-\sin\frac6x
$$

Comment: Thank you I now I understand but I dont know why the absolute value don't do from negative sine positive sine? I thought that absolute value change negative value to positive value? Am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "negative sine" and "positive sine". Grab a calculator and type $-\sin(6/(-100))$. Or even better, think about it a little more :)

Comment: Thank you very much Now I understand :) You are open my eyes :D

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\sin(f(x)) \sim f(x) \text{  as   } f(x) \rightarrow 0$$

This follows directly from the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x}{9}\left | \sin \frac{6}{x} \right |=\frac{1}{9}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }x\left | \sin \frac{6}{x} \right |=\frac{1}{9}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }6\cos \frac{6}{x}\left | \sin \frac{6}{x} \right |'=\frac{6}{9}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\cos \frac{6}{x}=\frac{2}{3}$$